# Provide Frontend layout handle to Adminhtml to render Frontend page/blocks

Tags: adminhtml, layout, frontend, update-handle

I'm currently working on a project which requires an area in the Admin panel which allows the admin to modify order related data (custom data set on order items) that can only be handled through a custom made GUI using Backbone/FabricJS. This GUI operates as a pseudo Product Page to load product related data relevant to the tasks performed within the GUI. This is done through a route defined in my module, which also has an associated layout file with a single layout handle for the frontend route to the GUI. I would like to provide access to this GUI from within the Admin panel (specifically from the order edit page as a link/button), however it is proving difficult to add that layout handle (including it's updates) to the adminhtml layout.

Can anyone suggest a way to load frontend layout handles to the adminhtml layout XML to provide such functionality?

Frontend Layout XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout>
    <gui_index_index>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/gui.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
        <remove name="footer"/>
        <remove name="left"/>
        <remove name="header"/>
        <reference name="head">

            <!-- don't index the customizer -->
            <action method="setRobots"><value>NOINDEX,NOFOLLOW</value></action>

            <!--add productjs for options pricing-->
            <action method="addJs"><script>varien/product.js</script></action>
            <!--remove extraneous css -->
            <action method="removeItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/styles.css</name></action>
            <action method="removeItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/widgets.css</name></action>
            <action method="removeItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/cloud-zoom.css</name></action>
            <action method="removeItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/slider.css</name></action>
            <action method="removeItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/local.css</name></action>
            <action method="removeItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/mobile.css</name></action>
            <action method="removeItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/animation.css</name></action>
            <action method="removeItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/settings.css</name></action>
            <action method="removeItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/captions.css</name></action>
            <action method="removeItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/override.css</name></action>
            <action method="removeItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/print.css</name></action>
            <action method="removeItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/responsive.css</name></action>
            <!--remove extraneous js -->
            <action method="removeItem"><type>js</type><name>lib/ccard.js</name></action>
            <action method="removeItem"><type>js</type><name>scriptaculous/builder.js</name></action>
            <action method="removeItem"><type>js</type><name>scriptaculous/dragdrop.js</name></action>
            <action method="removeItem"><type>js</type><name>scriptaculous/controls.js</name></action>
            <action method="removeItem"><type>js</type><name>scriptaculous/slider.js</name></action>
            <action method="removeItem"><type>js</type><name>lib/ccard.js</name></action>
            <action method="removeItem"><type>js</type><name>queldorei/cloud-zoom.1.0.2.min.js</name></action>
            <action method="removeItem"><type>js</type><name>queldorei/jquery.ui.totop.js</name></action>
            <action method="removeItem"><type>js</type><name>queldorei/jquery.hoverIntent.min.js</name></action>
            <action method="removeItem"><type>js</type><name>queldorei/jquery.masonry.min.js</name></action>
            <action method="removeItem"><type>js</type><name>queldorei/jquery.anystretch.min.js</name></action>
            <action method="removeItem"><type>js</type><name>queldorei/jquery.mousewheel.js</name></action>
            <action method="removeItem"><type>js</type><name>queldorei/jquery.easing.js</name></action>
            <action method="removeItem"><type>js</type><name>queldorei/jquery.flexslider-min.js</name></action>
            <action method="removeItem"><type>js</type><name>queldorei/jquery.themepunch.plugins.min.js</name></action>
            <action method="removeItem"><type>js</type><name>queldorei/jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js</name></action>
            <action method="removeItem"><type>js</type><name>queldorei/jquery.jcarousel.min.js</name></action>
            <action method="removeItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/enterprise/catalogevent.js</name></action>
            <action method="removeItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/enterprise/wishlist.js</name></action>
            <action method="removeItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/script.js</name></action>
            <!--add customizer css / js -->
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/customizer.css</name></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>js/bootstrap-timepicker/bootstrap-timepicker.css</name></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/customizer/customizer.js</name></action>
            <!--add smallipop css from git submodule repo -->
            <action method="addItem"><type>js_css</type><name>lib/smallipop/css/jquery.smallipop.min.css</name></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="core/text_list" name="product.json">
                <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.options.json" template="gui/product/view/view.phtml">
                    <block type="gui/catalog_product_view" name="product.info.options.wrapper" as="product_options_wrapper" template="gui/product/view/options/wrapper.phtml" translate="label">
                        <label>Info Column Options Wrapper</label>
                        <block type="catalog/product_view_options" name="product.info.options" as="product_options" template="catalog/product/view/options.phtml">
                            <action method="addOptionRenderer"><type>text</type><block>catalog/product_view_options_type_text</block><template>catalog/product/view/options/type/text.phtml</template></action>
                            <action method="addOptionRenderer"><type>file</type><block>catalog/product_view_options_type_file</block><template>catalog/product/view/options/type/file.phtml</template></action>
                            <action method="addOptionRenderer"><type>select</type><block>catalog/product_view_options_type_select</block><template>catalog/product/view/options/type/select.phtml</template></action>
                            <action method="addOptionRenderer"><type>date</type><block>catalog/product_view_options_type_date</block><template>catalog/product/view/options/type/date.phtml</template></action>
                        </block>
                        <block type="gui/bundle_catalog_product_view_type_bundle" name="product.info.bundle.options" as="type_bundle_options" template="bundle/catalog/product/view/type/bundle/options.phtml">
                            <action method="addRenderer"><type>select</type><block>bundle/catalog_product_view_type_bundle_option_select</block></action>
                            <action method="addRenderer"><type>multi</type><block>bundle/catalog_product_view_type_bundle_option_multi</block></action>
                            <action method="addRenderer"><type>radio</type><block>bundle/catalog_product_view_type_bundle_option_radio</block></action>
                            <action method="addRenderer"><type>checkbox</type><block>bundle/catalog_product_view_type_bundle_option_checkbox</block></action>
                        </block>
                    </block>
                </block>
                <block type="gui/bundle_catalog_product_view_type_bundle" name="bundle.tojson" template="gui/product/view/type/bundle.phtml" />
                <block type="gui/catalog_product_view" name="product.sides" template="gui/product/view/sides.phtml" />
            </block>
            <block type="core/template" name="options_js" template="catalog/product/view/options/js.phtml" output="toHtml"/>
        </reference>
        <reference name="product.options.json">
            <block type="bundle/catalog_product_view_type_bundle" name="product.info.bundle" as="product_type_data" template="bundle/catalog/product/view/type/bundle.phtml">
                <action method="addPriceBlockType"><type>bundle</type><block>bundle/catalog_product_price</block><template>gui/product/view/price.phtml</template></action>
            </block>
        </reference>
        <reference name="before_body_end">
            <block type="core/text" name="amd.js.loader">
                <action method="setText"><text><![CDATA[<script data-main="/js/customizer/main" src="/js/lib/requirejs/require.js"></script>]]></text></action>
            </block>
            <block type="core/text" name="font.js.loader">
                <action method="setText"><text><![CDATA[<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1.5.0/webfont.js"></script>]]></text></action>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </gui_index_index>
    <gui_project_load>
        <update handle="gui_index_index"/>
        <remove name="product.json"/>
    </gui_project_load>
</layout>
```

Adminhtml Layout XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout>
    <adminhtml_gui_index>
              <update handle="gui_index_index" />
    </adminhtml_gui_index>
</layout>
```

Adminhtml Index Action:

```
public function indexAction()
{

    $appEmulation = Mage::getSingleton('core/app_emulation');

    $initialEnvironmentInfo = $appEmulation->startEnvironmentEmulation('default','frontend');

/*        Mage::getDesign()->setArea('frontend');
        Mage::getDesign()->setTheme((string)Mage::app()->getConfig()->getNode('stores/default/design/theme/template'));
        Mage::getDesign()->setPackageName((string)Mage::app()->getConfig()->getNode('stores/default/package/name'));
*/
    //$this->getLayout()->getUpdate()->addHandle('gui_index_index');
    //$this->loadLayoutUpdates();

    //$this->loadLayout('gui_index_index', true, true);
    $this->loadLayout();
    //$this->getLayout()->getUpdate()->load('gui_index_index');
    //$this->getLayout()->generateXml();
    //var_dump(Mage::app()->getLayout()->getUpdate()->getHandles());die();
    $this->renderLayout();

    $appEmulation->stopEnvironmentEmulation($initialEnvironmentInfo);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, the cheapest way to achieve this is via environment app emulation, which it seems you're already doing. I would go ahead and pursue this route and look elsewhere in your layout definitions and local.xml for `remove` and `unset` definitions.

Something the below should coax the admin into loading the frontend root block for your design, but **you should expect to have to refactor your domain logic out of controllers** because it seems like your layout depends on the controller route. This can easily be handled by rather depending on `assign`:

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(24); //obviously this is being loaded in some other way

    $appEmulation = Mage::getSingleton('core/app_emulation');

    $initialEnvironmentInfo = $appEmulation->startEnvironmentEmulation('default','frontend');

    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->getLayout()->getBlock('root')->assign(array('current_product',$product));
    $this->renderLayout();

    $appEmulation->stopEnvironmentEmulation($initialEnvironmentInfo);

}
```